# Perl: Arrays to Methods and Back

Tags: arrays, perl

I have made a few methods. Calculate center of mass, translate the matrix according to the center of mass. The calculate center of mass works fine. x,y,z values are fine. However, I have trouble with passing and return of arrays in the translateMatrixOperation submethod.Essentially, translateMatrixOperation returns (\@translatematrix), and I am unable to access the elements in another method that calls the submethod. What is the problem here?

```
my @ref = calculateCenterMass(@matrix);
my $x = $ref[0];
my $y = $ref[1];
my $z = $ref[2];
print "Center of Mass for Matrix Above\n";
printf("X:%.3f,Y:%.3f,Z:%.3f\n\n",$x,$y,$z);
my @tempMatrix = translateMatrixOperation($x,$y,$z,\@matrix);
-----------------------------------------
sub translateMatrixOperation
{
  my ($x, $y, $z, $translatematrix) = @_;
  my $arrsize = @$translatematrix;
  for(my $i = 0; $i < $arrsize; $i++)
  {
    for(my $j = 0; $j < $arrsize; $j++)
    {
        if ($j == 0)
        {
            $translatematrix->[$i][$j] -= $x;
        }
        elsif ($j == 1)
        {
           $translatematrix->[$i][$j] -= $y;
        }
        elsif ($j == 2)
        {
            $translatematrix->[$i][$j] -= $z;
        }
     }
  }

 return (\@translatematrix);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice to return a array reference over just returning the array, usually comes down to size.

If you are transferring small arrays I would just write it with:

```
return @translatematrix;
```

If you are transferring large arrays ( large enough to affect the performance ), then I may possibly consider returning a reference.

I'm not really sure that you should be calling them matrices, since they appear to be an array of [cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). Which would be a lot easier to ponder over.

---

At any rate your code is quite verbose, and most likely wrong.

- It uses C style for loops, when it doesn't need to.

  [`foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loops are generally faster, and they are more explicit about what they are looping over.
- It loops over the inner array, even though you will almost always change exactly 3 of the values.
- Your inner for loop uses the length of the outer array, not the inner one.

  Which is a problem if the outer loop has less than 3 elements.
  It also means that when your outer array is large, your code spends a significant amount of it's time doing nothing.

  This is also another reason to use a [`foreach`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops) loop, you can't get the test part of it wrong.
- You modify elements of the original array.
- You return a reference to an array that you didn't actually use in the subroutine.

  I can only assume you don't have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your code, or you have declared `@translatematrix` somewhere else in your code.

Here is a version that still modifies the original array. ( Maybe that is what you actually wanted )

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @matrix = ...;

# no need for a temporary variable
my ($x,$y,$z) = calculateCenterMass(@matrix);

print "Center of Mass for Matrix Above\n";
printf( "X:%.3f,Y:%.3f,Z:%.3f\n\n", $x, $y, $z );

# it returns a reference, not an array.
my $tempMatrix = translateMatrixOperation( $x, $y, $z, \@matrix );

sub translateMatrixOperation {
  my ($x, $y, $z, $translate_matrix) = @_;

  for my $xyz ( @$translate_matrix ){
    $xyz->[0] -= $x;
    $xyz->[1] -= $y;
    $xyz->[2] -= $z;
  }

  return @$translate_matrix if wantarray;
  return $translate_matrix;
}
```

Here is a version that creates a new array.

```
my $tempMatrix = translateMatrixOperation( $x, $y, $z, @matrix );

sub translateMatrixOperation {
  my ($x, $y, $z, @coord) = @_;

  # This is here in case you give it an array reference like you did before.
  # It is quite fragile, you should remove it if you don't need it.
  if( 1
    and @coord == 1
    and ref( my $aref = $coord[0] ) eq 'ARRAY'
    and ref($aref->[0]) eq 'ARRAY'
  ){
    @coord = @$aref;
  }


  # create a new list
  my @return = map{
    # of a new array refs based on the old ones
    [ $_->[0] - $x, $_->[1] - $y, $_->[2] - $z, @$_[3..$#$_] ]
    # the @$_[3..$#$_] part may be unnecessary
    # it should be removed if that is the case
  } @coord;

  return @return if wantarray;
  return \@return;
}
```

If you remove the parts that I don't think you need, it gets quite short

```
my $tempMatrix = translateMatrixOperation( $x, $y, $z, @matrix );

sub translateMatrixOperation {
  my ($x, $y, $z, @coords) = @_;

  my @return = map{
    [ $_->[0] - $x, $_->[1] - $y, $_->[2] - $z ]
  } @coords;

  return @return if wantarray;
  return \@return;
}
```

You should also figure out a better name for it, `translateMatrixOperation` isn't very descriptive.

Comment: what does the map method do? I don't know what the line which says map{...} means.

Comment: @user2657817 the [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html "perldoc -f map") statement (in the last code block) is almost the same as `my @return; for( @coord ){ push @return, [ $_->[0] - $x, $_->[1] - $y, $_->[2] - $z ] }`. Perl is actually very well [documented](http://perldoc.perl.org/). (I learned Perl mostly from reading the docs.) If you are serious about learning Perl, I would go to [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) where there are links to various texts which will help you on your journey.

Answer (score 5):

The subroutine returns a reference to the array. You are storing the result in an array @tempMatrix. Therefore, the whole matrix is stored at `$tempMatrix[0]`.

It is probably not what you wanted. If a subroutine returns a reference, use a scalar variable to keep it, or dereference it before assigning the result to an array:

```
my $array_ref = translateMatrixOperation($x,$y,$z,\@matrix);
my @array     = @{ translateMatrixOperation($x,$y,$z,\@matrix) };
```

The latter option is slower and more memory intensive, because the array must be copied.